# Howto set values of hashmap from Java class in JSP page for further usage in controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Need some help solving the following issue.

I have web-application in Java, with Spring (mvc, security), Hibernate, and so on. 
Web pages sources are in JSP

I have a list of variables-indices, for which I need to set values and then automate it's processing. Say, client sees them in format:

```
A1.1 - Description - Dropdown list(0, 0.5, 1)
A1.2 - Description - Dropdown list(0, 0.5, 1)
...etc
```

Domain object is:

```
public class A1Model {
    private HashMap<Integer, Double> map;
    //initilising, getter and setter for map object
}
```

JSP page I have:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="m1ChapterModel" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
        <c:forEach items="${m1ChapterModel.map}" var="m1_parameter_i">           
                    A1.${m1_parameter_i.key}
                <spring2:message code="M1.1.label"/>
                <form:select path="${m1ChapterModel.map[m1_parameter_i.key]}">
                    <form:option value="0"/>
                    <form:option value="0.5"/>
                    <form:option value="1"/>
....
```

But thats not working, of course. The problem is:

```
<form:select path="${m1ChapterModel.map[m1_parameter_i.key]}">
```

Question is: how can i modify Java class and JSP to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
<form:select path="${m1ChapterModel.map[m1_parameter_i.key]}">
```

use

```
<form:select path="map[${m1_parameter_i.key}]">
```

because the path variable wants the path, not the concrete value

Comment: `<form:select path="map[${m1_parameter_i.key}]">`
That works, thank You for Your quick answer!

Comment: Right, you are inside the form, I removed the "prefix".